# Strange error in ciBonfire

Tags: php, codeigniter, conditional-statements

1st case : $oTask->task_versions is false / $oTask->aAttachments is false

Code :

```
<?php if(($oTask->task_versions) || ($oTask->aAttachments)): ?>
```

Here is what I am getting in my view :

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function  () in
>   /xxx/bonfire/modules/projects/views/tasks/index.php on line 60

---

2nd case : $oTask->task_versions is true / $oTask->aAttachments is true

Code :

```
<?php if(($oTask->task_versions) || ($oTask->aAttachments)): ?>
```

All Ok

---

3rd case : $oTask->task_versions is true / $oTask->aAttachments is true

Code :

```
<?php if($oTask->task_versions || $oTask->aAttachments): ?>
```

Here is what I am getting in the view :

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in
>   /xxx/bonfire/modules/projects/views/tasks/index.php
>   on line 60

---

4th case : $oTask->task_versions is false / $oTask->aAttachments is false

Code :

```
<?php if($oTask->task_versions || $oTask->aAttachments): ?>
```

Here is what I am getting in the view :

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /xxx/bonfire/modules/projects/views/tasks/index.php on line 60

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved it...

The solution is :

```
<?php if($oTask->task_versions||$oTask->aAttachments): ?>
```

It seems PHP does not appreciate space in "if" statements...